# How To Check For Non-Alphabetical Characters in String in C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

The below code (which compiles fine) checks for non-alphabetical characters in a command-line input, however I feel like there's got to be a better way to write this. For example, you can see that there is no code that executes in the core if statement that checks each character in the string. Is there a way to check if one of the characters is *not* an alphabetical character and throw the error, rather than have the error in the `else` function?

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]){

    // terminate program if more than one key
    if(argc != 2){

        printf("error");
        return 1;

    // check to ensure key characters are alphabetical
    } else {
        for(int h = 0; h < strlen(argv[1]); h++){
            if(isalpha(argv[1][h])){

            } else {
                printf("error");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `!` operator?

Comment: Why not just `if( ! isalpha(argv[1][h]))`, or am I missing something? BTW, what is that **`string`** in `string argv[]`?

Comment: @KenY-N Should be `char *`? In that case how should I iterate over the array of `char *` to check if each is alphabetical?
    `for(int h = 0; h < sizeof(argv[1]); h++){
        if(!isalpha(argv[1][h])){
            printf("error"); 
        }
    }` ?

Comment: 'h < strlen(argv[1])' expensive....

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Expensive how?

Comment: strlen() iterates the string, looking for the terminating NUL.... every time round the loop.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Got it! So I should create a global variable housing `strlen()` and just pass it in the `if` statement condition. Thank you!

Comment: Not a global variable; just a local variable.  You could use `for (int h = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); h < len; h++)` — or `for (int h = 0; argv[1][h] != '\0'; h++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are usually short, but calling strlen() ina for loop condition is a bad habit. It's O(N squared) because the entire string is scanned on each iteration.

Write the function like this

```
int allalpha(const char *str)
{
   size_t i;
   for(i=0;str[i];i++)
     if(!isalpha(str[i]))
        return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

Then in main

```
if(!allalpha(argv[1]))
{
   /* non all-alpha error handling code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can invert the if-condition, which is the general solution in these cases.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]){

    // terminate program if more than one key
    if(argc != 2){

        printf("error");
        return 1;

    } else {
        // check to ensure key characters are alphabetical
        for(int h = 0; h < strlen(argv[1]); h++){
            if(!isalpha(argv[1][h])){
                printf("error");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `!` operator is a boolean unary operator that will take any boolean condition and inverse its value. Now, in C booleans are actually really just integers, so in practice it will yield 0 (*false*) for a non-zero input (*true*), and 1 (*true*) for a zero input (*false*).